# Full desktop backup from Android

Tags: backup

Is there a reliable way to make a full desktop backup of all apps, app settings, files from an Android running Oreo?

I have tried using SDK and using the adb backup command. It seems to backup all the data but restore doesn't work. I have also noticed that backups made a few hours apart can be wildly different in terms of file size, which implies that it doesn't work consistently.

Is there something similar to the itunes back for iphone which works reliably?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- You can install a custom recovery (TWRP, Philztouch) depending on your phone's brand and unit.
- After installing, you can now perform nandroid backups and restore it anytime you want.

Comment: Please do mention that in this process the possibility of existing user data getting destroyed is incredibly high.

Comment: I have a Pixel 2 with a locked bootloader. Would TWRP work? I also saw the comment about possibility of data getting deleted. Any other methods which are more reliable? Thanks

Comment: Yes, of course, do it at your own risk. Google the process depending in your phone's unit.